# running a query and then running a query for each result of that query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that for a given date range tells me if a person was absent. So far i have two query's, one for getting every person and the date if they were scheduled to be in and one that if you pass it the card code of that person tells you how many times they have swiped on the clock in terminal, a number of swipes > 0 would tell me if they were in.

Here is the first query for getting each person and the date they were supposed to be in.

```
      SELECT
      CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardNo,
      CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name,
      LEFT(CONVERT(DATE, ATDScheduling.ScheduleDate), 11) AS Date1
    FROM CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel
      INNER JOIN
      CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.Reference
      INNER JOIN
      CHINA_VISION_PubCards ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      ATDScheduling ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = ATDScheduling.PubPersonnel_Ref
    WHERE
      (ATDScheduling.ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2015-02-12' AND '2015-02-22') AND (CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name <> 'null') AND
      (ATDScheduling.ATDShift_Ref > 1)
    ORDER BY CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name
```

this query produces a result like this:

```
  ClockNo |  Name     | Date should be in 
    5726    Person 1    2015-02-14
    5726    Person 1    2015-02-15
    5726    Person 1    2015-02-21
    5726    Person 1    2015-02-22
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-13
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-14
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-15
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-20
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-21
    5728    Person 2    2015-02-22
    5736    Person 3    2015-02-12
    5736    Person 3    2015-02-13
    5736    Person 3    2015-02-14
```

Here is the second query and the results when passes the Card code and date.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM CHINA_VISION_DorEvents
  INNER JOIN
  CHINA_VISION_PubCards ON CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode = CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardCode
WHERE (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.EventTM BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-12 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,102)) AND
  (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref = '16')
GROUP BY CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardNo
HAVING (CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardNo = '5726')
```

this query would have an out put like this:

```
Count 
  4
```

If the count is higher than 0 then they have swiped there card on the clock machine which indicates they were in. the amount they swipe doesn't really matter aslong as it's higher than 0

so for absences if the count is 0 then they were absent and that should increment the counter by one

What i would like the query out put to look like once theu are combined if possible

```
Clock Number  |    Name    |     Absence count
   5725           person 1             3
   5728           person 2             0
```

and so on.

Comment: Use a sub-query for both sets and join them together. Or go with a CTE, or just run your first query and then add a CROSS APPLY where you run the latter query. Or use temp / variable tables. :)

Comment: Could you provide an example how do this is? my Sql knowledge is not very good..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like CTEs for readability, and using NOT EXISTS vs OUTER APPLY because it's generally faster, but there are at least 4 or 5 different ways to write this query. Here is one example that shows how to get the absences. I also removed some unneeded code and simplified the query a bit. More comments inline:

```
/*
Since staff are always on the schedule (otherwise how could they be absent?), 
and we need their cards for the next query, let's do all INNER joins here.
We get one row per staffer, per day.
*/
With ScheduleCTE AS (
    SELECT
        c.CardNo,
        p.Name,
        s.ScheduleDate
    FROM
        ATDScheduling s
        INNER JOIN CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel p ON p.Reference = s.PubPersonnel_Ref
        INNER JOIN CHINA_VISION_PubCards c ON p.Reference = c.PubPersonnel_Ref
    WHERE
        s.ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2015-02-12' AND '2015-02-22'
        AND s.ATDShift_Ref > 1
)


/* 
not sure if your EventTM field includes time, so I'm trimming the time off both date fields to be safe. 
This slows the query, so avoid the type conversion if not necessary!
*/

SELECT
    s.CardNo,
    s.Name,
    COUNT(*) AS AbsentCount
FROM
    ScheduleCTE s
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
    --if staffer was present, let's remove him from the result
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM 
            CHINA_VISION_DorEvents e
        WHERE 
            e.CardCode = s.CardCode
            AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(s.Date1 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(e.EventTM AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
        )
GROUP BY
    s.CardNo,
    s.Name
ORDER BY s.Name
;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply, Just a couple things before i can start to understand this query, at line 14 
INNER JOIN JOIN CHINA_VISION_PubCards c ON p.Reference = c.PubPersonnel_Ref

Is a syntax error, im amusing the word join twice is a typo? 

Also Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
which is the AND CAST( . . . .  im not sure why this isn't working

Side note i am on SQL 2008

Comment: yes, that was a typo. and I missed an extra parenthesis on the date formula. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hi, using the new version, there are these two errors Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Invalid column name 'CardCode'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'Date1'.

Comment: With ScheduleCTE AS (
    SELECT
        c.CardCode,
        p.Name,
        s.ScheduleDate as Date1

This seems to do it, Is this what was intended?

Comment: CardCode and Date1  were in your original post. You'll need to edit the query if those aren't valid names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a WITH statement example. Not tested as I'm not 100% sure on how your queries work and I did it pretty quick. Basically using WITH you query Clocks_CTE on the second SELECT statement after ORDER BY CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name) The ; is needed before WITH

Kahn probably has a better idea to do this, but maybe this is a start.

```
--This is the first query which is stored in Clocks_CTE
;WITH Clocks_CTE
    (SELECT CHINA_VISION_PubCards.CardNo AS [ClockNum],
            CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name AS [Name],
            LEFT(CONVERT(DATE, ATDScheduling.ScheduleDate), 11) AS [Date1]
    FROM CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel
       INNER JOIN
           CHINA_VISION_DorEvents ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.Reference
       INNER JOIN
           CHINA_VISION_PubCards ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = CHINA_VISION_PubCards.PubPersonnel_Ref
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           ATDScheduling ON CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Reference = ATDScheduling.PubPersonnel_Ref
    WHERE (ATDScheduling.ScheduleDate BETWEEN '2015-02-12' 
    AND '2015-02-22') 
    AND (CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name <> 'null') 
    AND (ATDScheduling.ATDShift_Ref > 1)
    ORDER BY CHINA_VISION_PubPersonnel.Name)
-- End Clocks_CTE
-- You can now do a query on Clocks_CTE
-- Basic example query that you would need to modify
SELECT Count(ClockNum) AS [AbsenceCount],
       c.Name,
       c.ClockNum
FROM Clocks_CTE c
    INNER JOIN CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.CardCode ON c.ClockNum
WHERE (c.Date1 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-02-12 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,102)) 
AND (CHINA_VISION_DorEvents.DorCtrls_Ref = '16')
GROUP BY c.ClockNum
         c.Name
ORDER BY c.ClockNum
```